# How to solve too many files in uploads folder(s)?

Tags: uploads, media

my wordpress has this setting for upload - `.../uploads/{year}/{month}`

However I noticed that some folders (like `.../uploads/2023/06`) have 30+ thousands files.

So I want to relocate them to new subfolder (like `.../uploads/2023/06/21`).

However the problems are:

- file's link in posts
- file in media library

Does any one has idea how to relocate files and make changes in post(s) & library at once (php code, plugin etc)?

Thanks for ideas.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the files and use the **[Search & Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/)** plugin to easily change all occurrences of /uploads/2023/06 in your posts to /uploads/2023/06/21.
Note: before using the plugin, I recommend you to make a backup from your database.

Comment: Thanks for idea.

I solved it with wp_filesystem_direct::move() and update query with replace()